# Ansible variable precendence not respected

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

There is something I don't really get in Ansible documentation, about variables precedence.

which one wins  `group_vars/all` or variables defined in inventory ?doing the test shows that group_vars/all wins. but the documentation is confusing:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence

```
inventory file or script group vars 2  <-------
inventory group_vars/all <-------
playbook group_vars/all <--------
inventory group_vars/*
playbook group_vars/*
inventory file or script host vars 2 <---------
```

EDIT:I was expecting that the inventory wins but this is not the behavior I get .. all always wins:I can reproduce it here:

`inventory/myinv.yml`

```
all:
  children:
    test:
      hosts:
        127.0.0.1:
  vars:
    my_var: 'defined in inventory'
```

group_vars/all

```
my_var: 'defined in group vars'
```

playbook:

```
- name: 'Test'
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: 'debug var'
      shell:
        cmd: 'echo {{ my_var }}'
```

output:

```
TASK [debug var] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1] => changed=true 
  cmd: echo defined in group vars
  delta: '0:00:00.001510'
  end: '2021-03-18 21:46:32.243425'
  rc: 0
  start: '2021-03-18 21:46:32.241915'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: defined in group vars
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
```

am I missing something ?!

thanks ! :)

Comment: You are defining a group var for group `all` in your inventory file which is overridden by `group_vars/all`, exactly as described in the doc. If you define the same var for a specific host in you inventory file, that one will win.... Unless you override it in `host_vatrs/yourhost`

Answer (score 2):

The result is correct. `group_vars/all`, in the directory where the playbook is stored, has precedence `5.playbook group_vars/all`. This is higher compared to `3.inventory file or script group vars`.